# Polymer: this.set is not updating parent element properties when changing sub properties

Tags: polymer

using Polymer 1.1. Data bindings doesn't seem to update correctly (as expected) with the following setup:

```
Polymer({
is: 'place-detail',
properties: {
  selectedplace: {
    type: Object,
    notify: true,
    reflectToAttribute: true  //testing
  }
},
observers: [
  'placeHandler(selectedplace)'
],
editName: function(newname) {
  if (newname !== this.selectedplace.name) {
    this.debounce('updateDescription', function(){
      this.set('selectedplace.name', newname);
      this.set('selectedplace.dirty', true);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
});
```

Passing a `newname` to the `editName` method updates the `selectedplace` object, and changes are propagated to data bindings watching `{{selectedplace.name}}` in the local DOM.

However, these changes are not propagated to the parent element property, nor any observers watching the object such as `placeHandler`. For observers to work, deep watching is required:

```
observers: [
  'placeHandler(selectedplace.*)'
]
```

Is this expected an behavior? If so, how do I propagate this change to the element attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similiar issue the other day and found that putting the observer on the parent element allowed me propagate the data upward. Here's a simplified version:

```
Polymer({
  is: 't-child',

  properties: {
    data: {
      type: Object,
      notify: true,
      value: function() {
          return {};
      }
    }
  },

  editData: function( newData ) {
    this.set( 'data.name', newData.name  );
  },
});
```

and the parent element:

```
<template>
  <t-child data={{data}}></t-child>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 't-parent',

    properties: {
      data: Object
    },

    observers: [
      'nameChange(data.name)'
    ],

    nameChange: function( newName ) {
      console.log( 'Name has been changed to: ', newName )
    },
  });
</script>
```

Although if you're not sure which properties will be set on that `data` object, I don't think there's any way around deep watching.